# How do you organize specific code for one or a few customers in your application?

Tags: language-agnostic, code-organization

When you implement customer-specific code, how do you organize it?

1. Do you write if-Statements directly in your code ? (if (customer == 20) then blah blah)
2. Do you have a special dll where you put all of the code for that customer?
3. Do you program a kind of "user exits", i.e. named functions that can be overloaded in a separate dll?
4. Or do you use a library / framework for that?
5. Or a better way?

Comment: We try to make everything as modular as possible, so that when someone needs custom code we can just drop an additional DLL in place.

Answer (score 1):

The if-statement solution has the flaw that you may need to modify your code many places for each new customer. A better way is to encapsulate the behaviour you want to vary in an interface, and then letting the existing code **delegate** the task to an instance of this interface. The design is then ready for any number of different behaviours.

Take it even one step further and design your code as a framework and then create an application project for each customer that uses the framework in addition to any customer-specific code. The framework can be version controlled and (internally) released, allowing customer applications to be unaffected by later releases of the framework.

I would recommend that you take a look at the book "Flexible, Reliable Software: Using Patterns and Agile Development". It is built up around this very question.